# mysql indexes of multiple column

Tags: mysql

This may be a stupid question but I can't help asking, just to verify.

According to mysql document,

If you have a 4-column index on (col1, col2, col3, col4), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), (col1, col2, col3) and (col1, col2, col3, col4).

My question is, how about (col1, col3, col4) or (col1, col2, col4)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said,

```
(col1, col3, col4) : Only for col1
(col1, col2, col4) : Only for col1, col2
```

Take a look at [Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) and [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Edit: Oh.. And by the way, EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ... Lets you see what indexes MySQL will be using for a query.

Comment: How sad. That means I'll need an index for (col1, col2, col3, col4) and another index for (col1, col3, col4)

Comment: @Eric: I know. It's not unusual that the indexes for a table can exceed the size of the data itself